# For what integer values of n is $\tan (\pi /n)$ an algebraic integer?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

In http://oberlin.edu/faculty/jcalcut/arctan.pdf Calcut implies that this is true except when n is of the form $2{{p}^{k}}$for p an odd prime and k a natural number. He shows earlier that $\tan (\pi /n)$ has degree $\varphi (n)/2\text{ or }\varphi \text{(n)}$depending on whether 4|n or not. My primary interest is in the related case of  ${{\tan }^{2}}(\pi /n)$ because it always has degree $\varphi (n)/2$ so it is a natural choice as generator for the maximal real subfield of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}{{({{\zeta }_{n}})}^{{}}}$ - which is usually written $\mathbb{Q}{{({{\zeta }_{n}})}^{+}}$. The traditional generator for this subfield is ${{\lambda }_{n}}=2\cos (2\pi /n)$ - which is always an algebraic integer, but of course ${{\tan }^{2}}(\pi /n)$  is not always an algebraic integer.

Comment: This is the same as asking when $\left[ \frac{\zeta -1}{\zeta +1} \right]$ is an integer, and Mathematica appears to agree with Calcut, but there should be a simple proof.